# How to programatically set peekHeight for Android Compose BackdropScaffold

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can i programmatically set the `peekHeight` of `androidx.compose.material.BackdropScaffold`, so that the `frontlayer` is exactly underneath the `appBar`?

I have this code to build the app bar

```
@Composable
fun MyAppBar(backdropRevealed: Boolean, onBackdropReveal: (Boolean) -> Unit = {}) {

        var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
    
        SmallTopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier.onSizeChanged { size = it },
            title = {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Box(
                        Modifier
                            .width(48.dp)
                            .toggleable(
                                value = backdropRevealed,
                                onValueChange = { onBackdropReveal(it) },
                                indication = rememberRipple(bounded = false, radius = 56.dp),
                                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
                            ),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
                    ) {
                        AnimatedContent(
                            targetState = backdropRevealed,
                            transitionSpec = {
                                if (targetState) {
                                    fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 240, delayMillis = 120, easing = LinearEasing)) with
                                            fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 120, easing = LinearEasing))
                                } else {
                                    // Reveal to conceal
                                    fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 180, delayMillis = 90, easing = LinearEasing)) with
                                            fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 90, easing = LinearEasing))
                                }.using(SizeTransform(clip = false))
                            },
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
                        ) { revealed ->
                            if (revealed) {
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.Default.Close,
                                    contentDescription = "Close"
                                )
                            } else {
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.Default.Menu,
                                    contentDescription = "Menu"
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Text(
                        text = "My App",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
                    )
                }
            },
            actions = {
                IconButton(onClick = { Timber.e("Display Overflow app bar actions") }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.MoreVert,
                        contentDescription = "Localized description"
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

and my variable size does contain the actual height

i cannot see how to pass this to my BackdropScaffold to set its peekHeight

heres the Backdrop code

```
val myAppBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {
    MyAppBar(
        backdropRevealed = backdropRevealed,
        onBackdropReveal = {
            if (!scaffoldState.isAnimationRunning) {
                backdropRevealed = it
                scope.launch {
                    if (scaffoldState.isConcealed) {
                        scaffoldState.reveal()
                    } else {
                        scaffoldState.conceal()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
}

BackdropScaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    gesturesEnabled = false,
    appBar = myAppBar,
    backLayerBackgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
    backLayerContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary,
    backLayerContent = { ShowcaseBackLayerContent() },
    frontLayerContent = { ShowcaseFrontLayerContent() },
    frontLayerScrimColor = Color.Unspecified,
    peekHeight = 70.dp
) {

}
```

how can i programmatically set `peekHeight` to the `size.height`?

Comment: What does `onSizeChanged ` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works when you get size from Modifier.onSizeChanged and pass it via a callback to your BackdropScaffold

```
@Composable
private fun MyComposable() {

    val backdropScaffoldState =
        rememberBackdropScaffoldState(initialValue = BackdropValue.Revealed)

    var peekHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(BackdropScaffoldDefaults.PeekHeight) }
    val density = LocalDensity.current

    BackdropScaffold(
        appBar = {
            MyAppBar(true,
                onSizeChanged = {
                    with(density) {
                        peekHeight = it.height.toDp()
                    }
                },
                onBackdropReveal = {

                }
            )

        },
        scaffoldState = backdropScaffoldState,
        peekHeight = peekHeight,
        backLayerContent = {
            BackLayerContent()
        },

        frontLayerContent = {
            FrontLayerContent()
        }
    ) {

    }
}

@Composable
fun FrontLayerContent() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("Back Layer", fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}

@Composable
fun BackLayerContent() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text("Back Layer", fontSize = 40.sp, color = Color.White)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyAppBar(
    backdropRevealed: Boolean,
    onSizeChanged: (IntSize) -> Unit,
    onBackdropReveal: (Boolean) -> Unit = {}
) {

    var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

    SmallTopAppBar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .onSizeChanged {
                size = it
                onSizeChanged(it)
                println(" SIZE: $size")
            },
        title = {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .width(48.dp)
                        .toggleable(
                            value = backdropRevealed,
                            onValueChange = { onBackdropReveal(it) },
                            indication = rememberRipple(bounded = false, radius = 56.dp),
                            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
                        ),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
                ) {
                    AnimatedContent(
                        targetState = backdropRevealed,
                        transitionSpec = {
                            if (targetState) {
                                fadeIn(
                                    animationSpec = tween(
                                        durationMillis = 240,
                                        delayMillis = 120,
                                        easing = LinearEasing
                                    )
                                ) with
                                        fadeOut(
                                            animationSpec = tween(
                                                durationMillis = 120,
                                                easing = LinearEasing
                                            )
                                        )
                            } else {
                                // Reveal to conceal
                                fadeIn(
                                    animationSpec = tween(
                                        durationMillis = 180,
                                        delayMillis = 90,
                                        easing = LinearEasing
                                    )
                                ) with
                                        fadeOut(
                                            animationSpec = tween(
                                                durationMillis = 90,
                                                easing = LinearEasing
                                            )
                                        )
                            }.using(SizeTransform(clip = false))
                        },
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
                    ) { revealed ->
                        if (revealed) {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Default.Close,
                                contentDescription = "Close"
                            )
                        } else {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Default.Menu,
                                contentDescription = "Menu"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                Text(
                    text = "My App",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
                )
            }
        },
        actions = {
            IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Rounded.MoreVert,
                    contentDescription = "Localized description"
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: thank you, One day I will get the hang of kotlin callbacks ;)